# Project specific .lldbinit in current working directory not read by Xcode

Tags: xcode, lldb

I want to setup project specific .lldbinit files, so that "everything" would be under version control and easily setup in new computers. However it seems like **I can read only ~/.lldbinit file** and not any ~/git/project/.lldbinit files.

LLDB manual say:

> lldb will read settings/aliases/commands from three files at startup, if
>        they exist.
>
> **First**, it will read a ~/.lldbinit-debugger command file.  If you are
>        using the lldb command line interface, this is ~/.lldbinit-lldb.  If you
>        are using lldb inside a GUI debugger like Xcode this will be ~/.lldbinit-
>        Xcode.  This is a useful place to put settings that you want to apply
>        only when a given lldb command interpreter is used.
>
> **Second**, ~/.lldbinit is read.
>
> **Third**, an .lldbinit file in the current working directory (where lldb is
>        started) will be read.

So my question is: how do I setup Xcode or project to use the "third" option i.e. read .lldbinit file from the current working directory? How would I check or change what's Xcode's "current working directory"?

Comment: OK "an .lldbinit file in the current working directory" is the way to go; so the question to you is what is your cwd set to when you debug?  Arrange for the `.lldbinit` file to be in that directory and it should work.

Comment: That's what manual says, but in real life Xcode (6.3.1) didn't read it. Starting LLDB via Xcode debugging, not directly by myself.

Comment: And you're certain the Xcode scheme has the working directory set to directory holding the `.lldbinit` file?

Comment: Can't find "working directory" in scheme - run - options! Seen it earlier, not any more. Otherwise everything is Xcode default and simulator cwd is file:///Users/jounimiettunen/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/803E4D69-E98D-45B7-8E70-5B19FF0BE799/data/Containers/Data/Application/E375AEBF-2D43-4B99-8A91-86AFB4558DD6/

Comment: One approach is to have a build script that copies the project `.lldbinit` file into either the app bundle or to `~/.lldbinit-Xcode`.

Comment: and finally where to place it? Where is this directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now a "Xcode plugin to load project specific .lldbinit" at https://github.com/alloy/lldb-is-it-not

Answer (score 7):

Xcode now (written with the public Xcode 12) has support for setting a scheme-level `LLDB Init File`. This can be done as part of the Info tab in the Run phase of the scheme.

1. Open project in Xcode.
2. `⌘ + Shift + ,` to open scheme editor.
3. Select Run then the Info tab.
4. Edit `LLDB Init File` value.

   - Use `$(PROJECT_DIR)` to reference the directory that contains the project.
   - Use `$(SRCROOT)` to reference the target's source root directory.

[image: Xcode scheme editor]

Comment: Is it just me or the variables `$(PROJECT_DIR)` and `$(SRCROOT)` don’t work? When I specify full path, the file is properly loaded, but whenever I use these variables, it gets ignored.

Comment: This is my problem, using Big Sur 11.5.2, and Xcode 12.3 (12C33)

I also note that lldb init paths in the schema editor that contain a  ~, as in paths such as ~/.lldbinit, don't work. 

COMMON, APPLE. ISOLATING THIS COST ME A WEEK OF MY TIME.

Answer (score 3):

This is the working directory in which you launch whatever process loads the LLDB framework.  Xcode doesn't have a useful working directory (it was `/` last time I looked), so you can't really use the cwd version.

A solution for Xcode project specific lldb settings that will work in many cases is to put a symbolic breakpoint on main, set it to auto-continue, then put the settings you want in the breakpoint commands of that breakpoint.

It would also be great if Xcode had some UI to specify target-specific lldbinit files.

Comment: Is this still the case in XCode8 or is there a neat way to provide (and use) a '.lldbinit'-file together with the Xcode project in the meanwhile?

Comment: Xcode does not currently have a way to add a project or target specific lldbinit file.

Comment: If you will be attaching to processes that are already running, then rather than putting the breakpoint on `main` you may want to put it on a function that runs frequently. In that case you probably also want to set the breakpoint with `--thread-index 1 --one-shot true`. (And regardless of whether you use `main` or not, you likely want to set it with `--auto-continue true`). A heavily commented example of doing this can be found in the [Mozilla help page for using Xcode to debug Mozilla apps](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_on_Mac_OS_X#Setting_up_lldb)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode now has support for Target specific lldb init files.  There's an entry form for the path to the file in the Run scheme for the Xcode target.